# Unable to install cav-linux (comodo antivirus)

Tags: unity

I am using ubuntu 16.04 on my new Dell laptop. I just have this laptop 2 days ago, and I am new to Linux. I download this software this afternoon but unable to install. It has a waiting to install icon on the Unity Launcher column. I also installed the Deb packet installer. How can I put it into the Deb packet installer? or any other way to install this software. Thank you very much for your helps in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The Comodo linux antivirus hasn't seen real care in years. I think the last time I looked at it (perhaps mid 2016), the version still being offered was from 2013. While it is the definitions that matter most, I opted for Sophos antivirus on Linux. It takes a little more work to get it installed, but it is well documented and actively maintained.

They are the only AV vendor that seems to still be active in their support of Linux for the home user.

While not directly in answer to the OPs question, I think trying to wrestle with an installer that's designed for much older releases of Ubuntu isn't the correct road forward.

https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-linux.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I did install sophos-av. The software located at /opt directory.  I went to bin directory and ran the command sudo savscan -all /.  However, it showed "could not open file" for all of them. Please help if you could. Thank you very much for your helps in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest a screenshot to http://picpaste.com and maybe I can give a thought.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. However, I was just be able to use Avast to scan my system.  So, I decided to use Avast from now on.